# How can I upload both my express backend and react frontend to github?

Tags: node.js, github, visual-studio-code, push

This is what my file structure looks like:

[image]

I wanted to know how I can push both those files which look like this, to github:
[image]

I did `git init` at the root of the folder `cpp-queens` and I was only able to push my backend files, my react files didn't show up in the "stage changes" section. How can I get both to show up and push them both?

EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I tried these following commands:

[image]

Also, should I have removed the `.gitignore` file in my frontend react folder? I tried adding it back and this is what I see now:

[image]

And here is what my source control looks like:

[image]

And this is what my github page looks like now:

[image]

I don't know what's going on, could I have some more help?

Comment: did you `git add frontend` and `git commit -m "Added frontend files" to stage and commit the new files? If not, run those, then running `git push <branch>` should work fine.

Comment: I did what you said and I edited my post according to it, could you please check it out?

Comment: you have a repo inside a repo that is the problem, the yellow text

Comment: how can I fix that? also, how can I re-add `.gitignore` to my frontend to block out the `node_modules`, because apparently my `.gitignore` at the root of my project doesn't block it out for my frontend folder which is why there's over 10K changes in source control

Comment: remove the `.git` folder inside of frontend, then redo the above steps. If you have git inside of git, that's classed as submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the GitHub Desktop app, it makes everything more intuitive to use.
Good luck!

Comment: If I already commited and stuff using VSCode, will it affect it in anyway? Also, do I just open the folder in which I'm working on?

Comment: not too sure, maybe try creating a new repository in git to test it out and see if it would work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).